# Nginx configuration for static html-css

Tags: html, nginx, nginx-location

I have the below configuration for nginx,

```
server {
    listen 80;

    root /vol/www/home;
    index /index.html;

    error_page 404 /404.html;
    location = /404.html {
        internal;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
    location /about {
        try_files /about.html =404;
    }
}
```

this is working well, but when I select some paths in the home page say **About Us** page, the uri comes with the full filename including the ending `.html`. I was able to get ride of those by adding a separate location in the nginx configuration and changing all the href links to the location instead of filename. So that is one workaround to get ride that but to run locally without server it is not possible.

I have seen a `rewrite` config in nginx, but I was unsuccessful with that. So I am here to ask how do I setup the uri without a html part in it and without modifying the href path to a uri instead of filename.

My configuration is like so, but it is not working

```
server {
    listen 80;

    root /vol/www/home;
    index /index.html;

    error_page 404 /404.html;
    location = /404.html {
        internal;
    }

    location / {
        rewrite ^\/(.*)(\.html)?$ /$1 last;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
    }
}
```

A 500 error is thrown : rewrite or internal redirection cycle while processing "/"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace this to

```
   rewrite ^\/(.*)(\.html)?$ /$1 last;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
```

this

```
rewrite ^(/.*)\.html(\?.*)?$ $1$2 permanent;
rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 permanent;

try_files $uri/index.html $uri.html $uri/ $uri =404;
```

Comment: can you tell what is wrong with mine and why the error came up

Comment: your last code line is missing some codes. that's why

Comment: did mine worked?

Comment: Yes it is working I guess. but I have a test server setup in docker container and 80 port is exposed to my systems 5000 and on sub directories the port is not available. Like `localhost/about` the expected actual should be `localhost:5000/about`. I am sure your answer will work fine with server since I will be using 80 only there. (Issue only when, directing to a path by clicking href links, if I type `localhost:5000/about` that will work as well)

Comment: okay. in order to run files in different ports you need to expose them. like this docker run --name myweb -d --expose=8000-8009

Comment: And use this link to understand what is a 500 error and what is the reason to occur  it. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/500